# Do we need CSRF verification for every POST request?

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms

I am just building a simple HTML form with POST method and unfortunately I am finding CSRF verification error.

This is just a simple html form using POST method on localhost. There are no cross sites involved. I could definitely fix it by using `csrf_token` but I still don't understand why django is asking me for that..

There are no re-directions/ iframes involved here...

So, why this is happening?? is this normal to all ??

```
# Also tried using RequestContext(request) but there isn't any change in the error

#settings.py 
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

#views.py 

# url for home page is "" i.e, http://127.0.0.1:8000/
def HomePage (request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = myForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            context = { "myForm" : myForm(choices),
                        "values" : data,
                       }
            return render_to_response("home.html", context)
    else:
        form = myForm(choices)
    context = {"myForm" : form}
    return render_to_response("home.html", context)   


# home.html 

<div id="pingmeeForm">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <table>
                    {{myForm.as_table}}
                </table>
                <input name="enter" type="submit" value="enter"/>
            </form>
            {{values}}
</div>

# forms.py

class myForm (forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, my_choices,*args, **kwargs):
        super(myForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Friends'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=my_choices)

    message = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: If you have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in your middleware in `settings.py`, then it will be checked for each `POST` request. You have remove that if you really don't want _CSRF_ feature, but that is not recommended though. Alternatively, use `{% csrf_token %}` in template or `csrf_excempt` for view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do a post request, you typically change the state of the server. If you change the state of the server, you don't want to allow other sites to do so. To protect against other sites issueing post-requests on your server, you add csrf protection. Therefore the solution should (imho) never be to remove the Csrf protection. Depending on the situation, either of the following two is the case:

1. Your post request does not change the state. In that case, make it a get request.
2. Your post request changes the state. You need CSRF.

Comment: This is a good answer but in my opinion misses a key point of CSRF. The malicious website is submitting the POST *using the credentials of a logged-in user* who visits the malicious site.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got but didn't show explains *exactly* what you are doing wrong: you should ensure that

> the view function uses `RequestContext`
>       for the template, instead of `Context`.

Comment: I added `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` but there isn't any change in the error msg